# How to build elevation scale from an RGB map?

Tags: python, rgb, data-conversion

I need to build a correspondence map between colors and altitudes. The elevation file has blue color for sea and green/yellow/brown colors for elevation. The advice says:

> Find the pixel of the Mont Blanc (4810 m).

[image: Text]

I'm working with Python. I don't know how to solve this. I converted the map into a NumPy array of shape (2860,4490,3) with RGB values and want to transform into (2860,4490) with elevation value in meter.

Comment: without any proper scale, how do you expect it to convert to meters?

Comment: I believe you have been given at least 1 more point whose height and color are known.

Comment: how have you "converted the map into a numpy array"? the [raster versions](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/figures/elevation-map-of-europe/) of that image are 2208 by 1971 pixels which isn't even the same aspect ratio as your array.  the least common color occurs in ~6500 pixels and is scattered over the alps and elsewhere

Comment: This is not the exact image i used, but it's totally similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the RGB image to HSV colorspace to see with 'Hue' landmass can be linearly mapped. Treat water separately.

- Read slide 13 [here](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/vis/lecture_notes/lecture5-2x2.pdf).
- Last answer [here](https://forum.image.sc/t/topography-calibrated-from-color-scale/2363/2) illustrates this.
- You could use scikit image for processing:

```
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv

rgb_img = np.array(your_image)
hsv_img = rgb2hsv(rgb_img)
hue_img = hsv_img[:, :, 0]
```

Taken from [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_rgb_to_hsv.html).

Comment: Good answer; thanks for taking the time to add resources. (Bytheway there's [matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv.html) in matplotlib too.)

Answer (score 1):

Here lowest(min_value) has the RGB color blue and highest (max_value)as the color Brown.
If we take all the distinct colors possible and use R, G, B as features we are supposed to project them in a 1D space.

So if R, G, B are considered as X, Y, Z 3D space, there exists a straight line between Blue min_value (x1, y1, z1) and Brown max_value (x2, y2,z2)

you can put x1 y1, z1 as 0, 0, 0 and transform (x2,y2,z2) -> (x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1)
This will give you simpler linear mapping that you can use to map to any intermediate point (x3,y3,z3) given you know the height of that point from the sea-level. The (x3,y3,z3) point so obtained is nothing but your RGB color with R=x3, G=y3, and B=z3
The pixel location of that color is your answer!

Comment: I'm not sur to understand what you mean ? I have all the rgb values for each pixel. I know that a blue one is convert into 0 and that the brown one is convert into 4810. But how should i transform the rest of values from 3D in 1D ?